# My pc with Asus Z170-A power ups automatically

Tags: motherboard, power-management

I have disabled all power on options in my BIOS however some input changes like mouse click or keyboard strokes power ups my computer.
It came like a mystery. Every time I shutdown my PC and come back several hours later it is ON!
It's main board is Asus Z-170A.

Are there any fixes for this?

Comment: Does the computer turn on even if you unplug the mouse and keyboard? Could you please try?

Comment: In case it does not happen when I unplug mouse and keyboard what would be the case?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, but I looked up that your motherboard shouldn't support powering the computer on with usb keyboards or mice. Can you verify that the computer is truly in off state and not for example in sleep or hibernate state?

Comment: I've tried to unplug mouse and keyboard. This time it did not power up automatically when I back to my computer next day. I don't know is it true or not, but this happens often after windows hibernation. I mean is it different to shutdown or hibernate, due to power up issues?